# Better presentation of Results

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

As a part of a database that i am developing i have a function that i developed in Access 2010 . on presenting it to my Superiors i was asked to enhance the presentation or Display. i am just hoping someone can Point me the right direction..

so basically i am inserting some values from one table to the other. but i first run Loops to determine which field names match and copy from the Import table only those fields which match for the target table. so far it works perfectly. no Problems. i am displaying the matching field names in a msg box. the code for this field Name comparision is as follows:

```
Private Sub Command50_Click()
Dim n As Long
Dim m As Long
Dim Ret_Type As Integer
Dim str As String
Dim stp As String
Dim mystr As String
Dim mysas As String
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim rs1 As DAO.Recordset

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("MLE_Table")
Set rs1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tbl_Import")


With rs
For n = 0 To .Fields.Count - 1
str = CurrentDb().TableDefs("MLE_Table").Fields(n).Name

With rs1
For m = 0 To .Fields.Count - 1
stp = CurrentDb().TableDefs("tbl_Import").Fields(m).Name
Debug.Print stp
    If str = stp Then
         mystr = mystr & str & ", "
         fnd = True
         Exit For
    End If
    Next m
If Not fnd Then mysas = mysas & str & vbCrLf
fnd = False     
End With
Next n
.Close
End With

Ret_Type = MsgBox("The Following Fields could not be found in your upload !!" & vbCrLf & mysas, vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, " MISSING DATA")
End Sub
```

now what my colleagues want is that this msg box is not sufficient.. they want a more detailed Display. maybe a form or a text file or something so that the user has a more clear Picture.

the Suggestion was to Show up all the fields of the target table and then Show the fields that matched as green or maybe a tick or checkmark.

i am sure this cannot be done in a msgbox. i know it sounds elegant and i am not sure it can be done. some colleagues say it can be.

can somebody Point me in the right direction or some Suggestion please. i am not experianced enough in Access, so this would be a learning experiance..

thanks in advance..

Comment: Do you know that you can create reports in ms access as well? See https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-simple-report-408e92a8-11a4-418d-a378-7f1d99c25304 However, your question is too broad because you are essentially asking us to help you design something without too much details.

Comment: what i am looking for is an opinion or Suggestion from more experianced programmers on how this can be done efficiently. or if anyone has done this before. i can give more Details if required. just let me know what... yes i do know about reports. that is an Option but this is to be done everytime a file is uploaded. so i am thinking a Report maybe too much, just want to Display something more efficiently..

Answer (score 0):

What I like to do when I want to show text or data that doesn't fit into a MsgBox (or isn't suitable), is to paste it to a new Notepad window:

```vb
    Shell "notepad", vbNormalFocus
    ClipBoard_SetData strText    ' google this function
    SendKeys "^V", True
```

Or if it's tabular data, I open Excel and write it to a new sheet.

Starting a separate application has the additional advantage that users can easily save the data, if necessary.

Comment: i was thinking of something similar to Excel.. i thought to write it to an Access table and bind it to a Pop up form.. the Problem with Notepad would be that i cannot do any form of formatting in it. like if i wanted to show some of the field names as green because they matched.. i could not do that.. right?

Comment: No, Notepad is for plain text only. If you have tabular data and want to format it, I would use Excel.